# Copy object from one node to another in Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Cloud Functions for Firebase, and I'm stuck with what seems to be a very basic operation.

If someone adds a post, he writes to `/posts/`. I want a portion of that post to be saved under a different node, called `public-posts` or `private-posts`, using the same key as was used in the initial post.

My code looks like this

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.copyPost = functions.database
  .ref('/posts/{pushId}')
  .onWrite(event => {
    const post = event.data.val();
    const smallPost = (({ name, descr }) => ({ name, descr }))(post);
    if (post.isPublic) {
      return functions.database.ref('/public-posts/' + event.params.pushId)
        .set(smallPost);
    } else {
      return functions.database.ref('/private-posts/' + event.params.pushId)
        .set(smallPost);
    }
  })
```

The error message I get is: *functions.database.ref(...).set is not a function*.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did I just use a plural functions where I shouldn't? Gonna test this right now...

Comment: Oh no wait, I need to invoke database(), right? "function" should still be "functions" I guess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make changes to the database in a database trigger, you either have to use the Admin SDK, or find a reference to the relevant node using the reference you've been given in the event.  (You can't use `functions.database` to find a reference - that's used for registering triggers).

The easiest thing is probably to use `event.data.ref` ([doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DeltaSnapshot#ref)) to find a reference to the location you want to write:

```
const root = event.data.ref.root
const pubPost = root.child('public-posts')
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much!